# Creating users to administer facebook Apps

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

This is not a direct programming question but its closely related.

I'm developing a facebook app for a company and I need a facebook user to administer the App. Obvioslly I don't want to use my private account.

When I create a new account to administer the App its considered by facebook as a fake user because it has no friends/posts/etc and only API calls. Soon enough facebook asks my to verify that account by phone and after that by goverment Id.

Even if I use my real account to develop, when my job is done, to whom I should transfer the administer rights? The CEO's real account? The secretary's real account?
It's looks absurd. 
Can anybody advise me how to do it the proper way ?

Thanks,
Vadim

It's

Answer (score 0):

An application must have an admin, a real world user.

I'd suggest you to add your client CTO as an admin.